# Is this is the right answer?

Tags: calculus

$$\int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(1+x^2)^n}dx \qquad
        \left\{\begin{matrix}
        x = \tan{u} \\
        dx = \frac{du}{\cos^2{x}}
        \end{matrix}\right.\\
        =
        \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \cos^{2n}{u} \cdot \frac{1}{\cos^2{u}}du 
        = \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \cos^n{u}du
        $$
    Knowing that
        $$\int \cos^n{x}dx = \frac{\cos^{n-1}{x}\sin{x}}{n}+\frac{n-1}{n} \int \cos^{n-2}xdx$$
We can conclude:
        $$J_n = \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \cos^n{u}du \xrightarrow[]{} nJ_n = (n-1)J_{n-2} \rightarrow J_n = \frac{n-1}{n}J_{n-2}$$
        $$J_1 = 1, J_2 = \frac{\pi}{4}$$

Comment: $cos^{2n} u / cos^{2} u$ does not equal $cos^{n}$, it equals $cos^{2n-2}$.

Comment: Oh right, sorry.

Comment: Than how do we solve 
$\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} cos^{2n-2}udu$?

Comment: Use integrate by parts on the first step, $\int cos^{2n}u d (tan u)$ instead of changing it to $cos^{2n-2}$

Comment: after doing by parts i get something like this:
$\cos^{2n}{u}\tan{u}+2n\int \cos^{2n-2}{u}\sin^2{u}du$
And it seems even harder than $\int cos^{2n-2}{u}du$

Comment: You are almost there, the steps are correct. Heres a final hint, change $sin^{2}u = 1 - cos^{2}u$, then write the integral as an equation with the starting integral on the left side, since you will get back what you started, so a little rearrangement would work.

Comment: Oh, got it. Thank you so much!